# Php free QR code generator

Tags: php, qr-code

Hi everyone I need a free for commercial use library to generate a QR code in php. Any suggestion? 
I've already seen Google API.

Comment: This is clearly off-topic, as it's requesting to recommend an off-site resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already tested this library and it works fine : http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

hope that helps :)